# Append JSON data to existing array of objects in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Consider I have an array

```
let array1 = [{a:1, b:2}, {e:5,f:6}]
let json1 = {c:3, d:4}
```

I want to append json1 to first item of array1 so the resultant looks like

```
array1 = [{a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4}, {e:5, f:6}]
```

I am sure push doesn't work here. I am not sure how to proceed further.

Comment: Or [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/171251/215552)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could assign the new data to the object.

```js
let array = [{ a: 1, b: 2 }, { e: 5, f: 6 }],
    data = { c: 3, d: 4 };

Object.assign(array[0], data);

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use spread operator

```js
let array1 = [{a:1, b:2}, {e:5,f:6}];
let json1 = {c:3, d:4};
array1[0] = {...array1[0], ...json1};
console.log(array1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try using [**`Object.assign()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

> The `Object.assign()` method copies all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object. It returns the target object.

```js
let array1 = [{a:1, b:2}, {e:5,f:6}]
let json1 = {c:3, d:4}
Object.assign(array1[0], json1);
console.log(array1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate using `map` and capture the first index and using the spread operator merge the `json` object with the first index.

```js
let array1 = [{a:1, b:2}, {e:5,f:6}]
let json1 = {c:3, d:4}

let res = array1.map((obj, i) => (i === 0 ? {...obj, ...json1} : obj));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through `json1` with `Object.keys()` and add the key value pairs:

```js
let array1 = [{a:1, b:2}, {e:5,f:6}]
let json1 = {c:3, d:4}

Object.keys(json1).forEach(ent => {
    array1[0][ent] = json1[ent]
})

console.log(array1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign alphabetically, you can use the char code

```js
let array1 = [{a:1, b:2}, {e:5,f:6}];
let json1 = {c:3, d:4};

const getCodeStartEnd = (obj) => {
    const keys = Object.keys(obj);
    return [keys.shift().charCodeAt(0), keys.pop().charCodeAt(0)];
};

const [start, end] = getCodeStartEnd(json1);
const res = [];

for (const j of array1) {
    const [f, l] = getCodeStartEnd(j);
    if (l + 1 === start) {
        res.push({...j, ...json1});
        continue;
    }
    res.push(j)
}

console.log(res);
```